# How to replace a string containing date and IP with sed command

Tags: sed, date, ip, replace

I have the following string of characters, including the IP address and date. For some security reasons, I need to hide the first two digits of the IP address.

```
text 200.200.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts
```

I did run the following command, but the `2022.05.07` also be replaced.

```
echo "text 200.200.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts"|sed -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\./IP./g'
text IP.10.2   2IP.07 15:32:43 other texts
```

I only want to replace `200.200.10.2`.

Comment: Two possibilities: Either you give a better pattern to include four numbers separated by three dots or (more simple) you leave away the `g`lobal flag to replace only the first occurence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` flag means "replace all occurrences of the string on the line". If you only want to replace the first occurrence, just remove the `g`:

```
$ echo "text 200.200.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts" | 
    sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\./IP./'
text IP.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts
```

Of course, the details depend on what you are trying to do. The command above would also replace `999.999.whatever` with `IP.whatever`, so maybe you want to only do this if there are exactly 4 groups of numbers:

```
$ echo "1.2.3 text 200.200.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts" | 
    sed -E 's/([0-9]{1,3}\.){2}([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/IP.\2/'
1.2.3 text IP.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts
```

But that would also match `1.12.123.1234567890`. So you might want to only match if the last set of numbers is followed by whitespace or the end of the line:

```
$ echo "1.2.3 text 200.200.10.2   2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts" | 
    sed -E 's/([0-9]{1,3}\.){2}([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}([[:blank:]]|$))/IP./'
1.2.3 text IP.  2022.05.07 15:32:43 other texts
```